# Does Universal-Image-Loader support progress bar while it is download a image from network?

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

Does Android Universal-Image-Loader support progress bar while it is download a image from network?

Comment: I think no. UIM has only complete,failed, started and finish listener.

Comment: Thanks Georgy, Thanks you.